# Rails Database Association / Migration

Tags: model, ruby-on-rails-3.1, database-migration

I'm learning rails and I'm trying to figure out database associations. If I have a database table with say Users that has an id, name, email, etc. and a Message table with the message, a sender (User) and recipient (also a User), how do I set up the migration and the models. Here, I'm using Rails 3.1. I'm pretty sure I can do it with just one User in the Message table with the references:User in the migration, but I'm not sure how to set up two of them.

Comment: OK, It looks like in my model I want something like:

`class Message
  belongs_to: sender, class_name => User
  belongs_to: recipient, class_name => User
end`

but I'm still not sure what I'd put in the migration to get the sender_id and recipient_id columns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some resources to get you started: [Rails Tutorial: User Model](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-and-viewing-users-one#sec:user_model) [RoR Guides: Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html)

First make your user migration

```
$ rails generate model User name:string email:string
```

Then your messages migration

```
$ rails generate model Message message:string user_id:integer
```

Then in your Messages model (/app/models/messages.rb)

```
belongs_to :user
```

And in your User model (/app/models/users.rb)

```
has_many :microposts
```

Obviously this is a rough sketch of what needs to happen, but that should get you started!

Comment: I can't add my comment under yours for some reason, but the comment you made doesn't change my answer. Reading a little from the links I posted would really help you understand what's going on I think.

Comment: Thanks, this is the book I'm using to figure things out. I've got the migration right now, and the Message model with two :belongs_to lines ...

`
    belongs_to :sender, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "sender_id"
    belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "recipient_id"
`

Now I'm not sure what should go in the User model. It seems like there should be two "has_many" lines one for sending and one for receiving, but I'm not sure exactly how to specify them. Thoughts?

Comment: OK, here's what I ended up with (apologies in advance for what I anticipate being f'd formatting ...

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's what I ended up with.

First the migration ...

```
class CreateMessage < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :messages do |t|
      t.string :greeting
      t.integer :sender_id
      t.integer :recipient_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Next in the Message model ...

```
# Message model
belongs_to :sender, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "sender_id"
belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "recipient_id"
```

and in the User model ...

```
# Message model
belongs_to :sender, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "sender_id"
belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "recipient_id"
```