# How to add a simple has_many association to a model in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations, rails-models

Hi I am pretty much a newb in RoR, which is why I have been stuck on something so basic, for past three hours or something.

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549167/rails-database-association-migration) question, which made me believe that to add a association I have to:

- Create the model (`rails generate model1`)
- Create the second model (`rails generate model2`)
- Then edit the `model1.rb` and `model2.rb` files, and specify `has_many :model2s` and `belongs_to :model1` in them respectively.
- Run rake `db:migrate`

I thought this was supposed to create the models, their respective tables in the database, and the reference in model2 table for model1. However, this last part hasn't been done.

Even the guides doesn't mention the exact steps required to add a association. The getting started guide tells to just add the association in the model file, and the Association Basics guide tells me *about* the association. Now how to add them so they're reflected in the database.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take the following steps. If you have two models - parent & child.

In the parent's model, add a **has_many** relationship.
In the child, add the **belongs_to** relationship.

Add a column to the child to hold the reference:

```
rails g migration add_parent_id_to_child parent_id:integer
```

Answer (score 1):

In your DB migration file, you'll have to add the foreign key manually unless you've specified that `model2` had `model1_id:integer` while generating the model like this :

```
rails generate model model2 model1_id:integer #Extra fields ...
```

Take a look at the doc here :
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-generate

Comment: So you're telling me, that specifying the association in the models is not enough. I have to be explicit about model2 having a model1 column. Either in the generate command or in the create migration? And it's not even mentioned explicitly in the guides.

Comment: Maybe follow a step by step tutorial that will show you how to do everything, it'll be easier to get starter : http://ruby.railstutorial.org/

Comment: Thank you for the correct answer. But I have marked the other answer as accepted, because that directly answers the question asked. But it was your answer that was sufficient to resolve my confusion.

Comment: Hey Caffeine, if you liked the answer please feel free to vote it up. Cheers.